# Apply effect to text in different div

Tags: css

I have a container div that lights up when you hover over it. It also changes the text effect as well. However, the text effect is only changed if the child div where this text is does not have a text effect itself. Can I somehow overwrite this text effect when the div is hovered, and then return it back when the mouse leaves? Thanks :))))

(Trying to overwrite the text shadow effect in the .text div.)

```
.maindiv2:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3C8DDE;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#599bdc), to(#3072b3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#599bdc, #3072b3);
cursor:pointer;
onclick="SomeJavaScriptCode";
}
.text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow:#ffffff 0px 0.05em  0px;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    width: 275px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

[JsFiddle with two divs showing one working and the other not :)](http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/nfQSA/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

```
.maindiv2:hover .text
{
    /* whatnot */
}
```

is an option, but it is not cross browser.

So in your situation you need this:

```
.maindiv:hover .text
{
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

just before the `.text` csss

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PPZbG/)**

Comment: Thanks, but this reduces the background color to only the text div.

Comment: I provided a jsfiddle to make it easier :)

Comment: +1 for the edited answer, which is the same idea as my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `.text`class selector overriding the parent selector attributes. The easiest option, I think, is to split the `text-shadow` into a separate rule which captures both requirements:

```
.maindiv:hover, .maindiv:hover .text {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

and remove the `text-shadow` from the single `.maindiv:hover` selector styles.

Comment: nice!  I like that better, splitting out the style into a separate one.  I had tried to just add the `.maindiv:hover .text` selector to the original rule but it didn't work. :P  splitting it out should though.

Comment: Both answers are great! Thanks Joseph and Andyb :)))))))))))))!